# Panel Dashboard Created in Google Colab and Viewed via ngrok Doesn't Display Content

Tags: google-colaboratory, panel, dashboard, ngrok, hvplot

I used the following code to create a dashboard in a google colab notebook:

```
!pip install --upgrade hvplot
!pip install --upgrade pyngrok
!pip install --upgrade pyngrok tornado
!pip install --upgrade bokeh
!pip install --upgrade holoviews
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import panel as pn
import bokeh
import tornado
import pyngrok
from pyngrok import ngrok
import hvplot.pandas
from bokeh.plotting import figure
pn.extension('tabulator')

# Generate some random data for the graph
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# Create the graph component using Bokeh
plot = figure(title='Sine Wave', width=400, height=300)
plot.line(x, y, legend_label='y=sin(x)', line_width=2)

# Create the BootstrapTemplate
template = pn.template.BootstrapTemplate(title='Graph Template')

# Create the sidebar components
sidebar = pn.Column(
    "# Graph Template",
    "This is a simple example of a graph template.",
)

# Create the main content components
content = pn.Column(
    pn.pane.Markdown("## My Graph"),
    pn.pane.Bokeh(plot),
)

# Set the sidebar and content
template.sidebar.append(sidebar)
template.main.append(content)

# Show the template
local_url = template.show()

port=local_url.port

ngrok.set_auth_token("<Insert Auth Token>") #Needs to be changed to your ngrok token

ngrok.kill()

# Start ngrok and create a public URL
ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(port)


# Print the public URL
public_url = ngrok_tunnel.public_url
print(" * ngrok tunnel \"{}\" -> \"http://127.0.0.1:{}\"".format(public_url, port))
```

The website found at the public url however only displays the title "Graph Template" and apart from that nothing else. I tried using matlab and other widgets from the panel package but none worked. Any ideas how to get this to work?